# Django ModelForm Validation not validating

Tags: python, django, django-validation

Can someone check what i'm omitting here?
The Validation error is not showing up even when it should. It's just returning successful when it should've showed a validation error.
When I run my server and insert a title less than 5 charcters, it still returns successful instead of raising a Validating error.

```
views.py;

def form_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return HttpResponse("successful")
        else:
            return render(request, "product_create.html", {'form': form})
    else:
        form = ProductForm(None)
        return render(request, 'product_create.html', {'form': form})

models.py;

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=250)
    price = models.FloatField()

forms.py;

from django import forms
from .views import Product


class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'price',
        ]

    def cleaned_title(self):

        title = self.cleaned_data.get('title')
        if len(title) < 5:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This is not a valid title")
        return self.cleaned_data


template;

product_create.html:
   {% block content %}
<form action="." method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>`enter code here`

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: To define a validation method for a specific field the method should be named `clean_<fieldname>`, in your case the method `cleaned_title` should be `clean_title` instead

Comment: And it worked. I have been struggling to debug this for days now, I became fraustrated.